# Alternative of Jsoup.parse() method

Tags: android, html, json, parsing, jsoup

I use `Jsoup.parse()` to parse [this data](http://api.3botinka.com/api/synchronize). Everything works good but takes to much time.

For example this data takes 20 sec. for parsing. Are there other solutions for my needs?

Code:

```
rezult = Jsoup.parse(res.parse().outerHtml(), "UTF-8").text();
```

Where `res` it's text from [link](http://api.3botinka.com/api/synchronize).

**=========== UPDATE =============**

I separate this variable from `Jsoup.parse()` and understood that it is the source of problem. It takes 20 seconds, not `Jsoup.parse()`.

```
String tmp = res.parse().outerHtml();
```

And this one takes only 1 sec.:

```
rezult = Jsoup.parse(tmp, "UTF-8").text();
```

I use this code to get data from this link. I use `Jsoup.parse()` because without it I got something like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    {&quot;success&quot;:true,&quot;currentUser&quot;:43743,&quot;careTypes&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;\u0421\u0442\u0438\u0440\u043a\u0430&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;\u041e\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0441\u0442\u0438\u0440\u043a\u0438 \u043f\u043e\u044f\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0437\u0434\u0435\u0441\u044c, \u043a\u0430\u043a \u0442\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043a\u043e \u0432\u044b \u0432\u044b\u0431\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0442\u0435 \u0440\u0435\u043a\u043e\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0434\u0443\u0435\u043c\u044b\u0439 \u0440\u0435\u0436\u0438\u043c.&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:2,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;\u041e\u0442\u0431\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;\u041e\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u0431\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f \u043f\u043e\u044f\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0437\u0434\u0435\u0441\u044c, \u043a\u0430\u043a \u0442\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043a\u043e \u0432\u044b \u0432\u044b\u0431\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0442\u0435
```

instead this:

```
{"success":true,"currentUser":43743,"careTypes":[{"id":1,"name":"\u0421\u0442\u0438\u0440\u043a\u0430","description":"\u041e\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0441\u0442\u0438\u0440\u043a\u0438 \u043f\u043e\u044f\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0437\u0434\u0435\u0441\u044c, \u043a\u0430\u043a \u0442\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043a\u043e \u0432\u044b \u0432\u044b\u0431\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0442\u0435 \u0440\u0435\u043a\u043e\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0434\u0443\u0435\u043c\u044b\u0439 \u0440\u0435\u0436\u0438\u043c."},{"id":2,"name":"\u041e\u0442\u0431\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435","description":"\u041e\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u0431\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f \u043f\u043e\u044f\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0437\u0434\u0435\u0441\u044c, \u043a\u0430\u043a \u0442\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043a\u043e \u0432\u044b \u0432\u044b\u0431\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0442\u0435
```

But now the main problem is to change `res.parse()` method to something other with less execution time.

**=========== UPDATE 2 =============**

```
 long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .ignoreContentType(true);
            if (data != null) {
                connection.data(data);
            }

            res = connection.execute();

            Logger.d(System.currentTimeMillis() - t2 + " = connection.execute");

            long t6 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            String tmp = res.parse().outerHtml();
            Logger.d(System.currentTimeMillis() - t6 + " = res.parse().outerHtml()");

            long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            rezult = Jsoup.parse(tmp, "UTF-8").text();
            Logger.d(System.currentTimeMillis() - t4 + " = Jsoup.parse");
```

And what I got in Logcat:

```
1588 = connection.execute
16150 = res.parse().outerHtml()
1466 = Jsoup.parse
```

Comment: It's not possible that it takes 20 seconds to parse that information. Why do you parse an already parsed result? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I updated post, look please.

Comment: It's still very unclear to me. What is the desired result? Can you give an example that shows exactly "this is the result I want"?

You should be aware that Jsoup cannot execute JavaScript, and if any of the text that you want to parse is rendered using JavaScript, you wont be able to parse it.

Comment: I want to get String variable with text from this link (http://api.3botinka.com/api/synchronize). I need exactly this text without any HTML tags. For this porpose I use Jsoup. JavaScript does not matter , it's impossible for current web page.

Comment: Post your code as a whole please

Comment: Check please I've added.

Comment: It's not the Jsoup parsing that takes time but most likely your connection that slows it down. Add some printouts and you'll be able to see where the code gets stuck, or use the debugger. With about 90% of the code you used above I was able to get the result in less than a second.

Comment: I added some points to check execution time. The most time cost method is parse().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem.

There is other method in `Jsoup` lib to get content of page without parsing.

The solution is change this line:

```
String tmp = res.parse().outerHtml();
```

on this line:

```
String tmp = res.body();
```

It is realy faster in 20 times. May be they do different work, but in my needs it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval()`. Also, be sure that the source being `eval()` is safe. `eval()` will attempt to evaluate any statement and thus can potentially expose security problems is not used properly

Comment: I don't know such method as eval(). Can you show how to use it in my case or give me a link on some documentation?

Comment: You just use eval() exactly as parse(), just use the word eval instead of parse.

Hope it will help...

Comment: Jsoup.Connection does not support this method. Are you sure that you use the same lib?

Comment: Ok. sorry p.Valery! I messed that you are using special lib.